# Copy-paste from PowerPoint to HipChat results in PNG, not text

Tags: hipchat

Whenever I try to copy text from a PowerPoint presentation into a HipChat chatroom, the text is copied as a PNG.

If I copy from PowerPoint to, say, Notepad++, the text is copied correctly.

I cannot find any mention of this problem on the HipChat help forum or elsewhere for that matter. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?